# Java Serialization without external dependency?

Tags: java

Is there a way to serialize Java object in any common formats like JSON, XML, YAML, etc. Without external dependency?

Or, with minimal single-file code that could be easily copy-pasted as a dependency?

The serialisation could be very simple, just walking on simple object/array tree and saving it into any text-based representation, without any configs or custom options.

P.S.

It should be automatic, not writing JSON manually or with XMLBuilder etc.

Comment: of course, use a `StringBuilder`. implement `Serializable` in each class you want to serialize and the a loop over your data structure.

Comment: @bb1950328 it should be automatic

Comment: You can use an [ObjectOutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html) to write objects that implement [Serializable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html). But that will create a binary stream / file that is not human readable.

Comment: Serialization is an easy job using a Reflection API: go through all object fields (including nested) and build a serialized string in a required format. The problem is *automatic* deserialization from a string format, I do not think it will be a trivial task.